# jquery json inside array to html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to get the simple table format from the json(results array) below, I wish to use jquery `.each`. I tried this code but how to get the object? I tried v.subject but doesn't work.

```
$.getJSON( "http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/list/?page=1&format=json", function( data ) {
   $.each( data, function() {
      $.each( this, function( i, v ) {
         console.log( v );
      });
   });
});
```

result of console.log(v)

```
 Object { subject="ronald birthday", date="2014-06-13", time_start="11:17 PM"}
 Object { subject="ronald birthday", date="2014-06-19", time_start="7:17 PM"}
```

This is the format table

```
      <table >

        <tr>
         <td> <a href="#"> Rita Birthday</a> </td>
         <td> <a href="#"> Oct. 18, 2014</a> </td>
         <td> <a href="#"> 11:27 PM</a> </td>
        </tr>

       </table>
```

This is the json but only the results array should be in the table:

> {"count": 18, "next": "http://www.nothingonlytest.com/ajax/list/?page=2&format=json", "previous": null, "results": [{"subject": "ronald birthday", "date": "2014-06-13", "time_start": "11:17 PM"}, {"subject": "ronald birthday", "date": "2014-06-19", "time_start": "7:17 PM"}, {"subject": "Rita Birthday", "date": "2014-10-18", "time_start": "11:27 PM"}, {"subject": "tt", "date": "2014-06-27", "time_start": "10:31 PM"}, {"subject": "tt", "date": "2014-06-13", "time_start": "10:31 PM"}, {"subject": "group event", "date": "2014-06-14", "time_start": "3:31 AM"}, {"subject": "test message", "date": "2014-06-17", "time_start": "3:32 AM"}, {"subject": "test event message", "date": "2014-06-14", "time_start": "3:34 AM"}, {"subject": "fd", "date": "2014-06-20", "time_start": "3:36 AM"}, {"subject": "fdf", "date": "2014-06-14", "time_start": "3:38 AM"}]}

Comment: the data that needs to be iterated is data.results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

1. You need to get the table object using [jquery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).
2. Then you need to loop the results property of the json data using [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) keyword.
3. For each object of the result, get the property of subject, date and time_start using [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).
4. Create a row string such as `"<tr><td>" + val1 + "</td><td>" + val2 + "</td><td>" + val3 + "</td></tr>"` and append it to the table object using [jquery append](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

## UPDATE

You need to loop the results property instead.

```
$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/list/?page=1&format=json", function( data ) {
   $.each(data.results, function() {
      $.each( this, function( i, v ) {
         console.log( v );
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: I really like to use .each than for loop and can you please post an example.